# bash variable with hash value assigned

Tags: bash, shell, echo

I have a variable that has a hash value assigned to it. For example :

```
hash=$1$qGqTE/jV$syM.7qpaKlCTsBXOYu2op/
```

now when I do `echo $hash` in bash it returns:

```
/jV.7qpaKlCTsBXOYu2op/
```

How do I have hash value not escape any characters? or have `echo $hash` return the entire string `$1$qGqTE/jV$syM.7qpaKlCTsBXOYu2op/`?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition needs single quotes:

```
$ hash='$1$qGqTE/jV$syM.7qpaKlCTsBXOYu2op/'
$ echo "$hash"
$1$qGqTE/jV$syM.7qpaKlCTsBXOYu2op/
```

Without the single quotes, the shell performs variable substitution and the result depends on the value returned by  `$1`, `$qGqTE` and `$syM` when the definition statement is executed.

I also added double-quotes to the `echo` statement.  This stops the shell from performing word splitting and pathname expansion.  While it may be unlikely that a hash value would be affected by these, it is safer to use the double quotes.  As an example of the potential problem:

```
$ hash='/bin/le*'
$ echo $hash
/bin/less /bin/lessecho /bin/lessfile /bin/lesskey /bin/lesspipe
$ echo "$hash"
/bin/le*
```

As you can see, in this case, `echo $hash` performs pathname expansion and returns a list of files.  `echo "$hash"`, however, works as desired.  To avoid surprises such as this, it is best to put references to shell variables in double quotes.

Comment: Thank you John. I just did! Appreciate it a lot!